# Thymeleaf nested list not working

Tags: nested, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get the nested list working in Thymeleaf. I have tried not nesting the list and the `entry.value` works. However when I start nesting it, it doesnt show up in the webpage. `Students` is a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

```
<ul th:each="entry : ${students}">
    <li th:text="${entry.key}">
        <ul>
            <li th:text="${entry.value[0]}"></li>
            <li th:text="${entry.value[1]}"></li>
            <li th:text="${entry.value[2]}"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently it looks like this. [image: temp]

Comment: `th:text` replaces all children.

Comment: @holmis83 sorry but can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`th:text` attributes replace all any child html elements with the contents of the `th:text` expression.  You have to move the th:text into it's own tag, something like this:

```html
<ul th:each="entry: ${students}">
    <li>
        <span th:text="${entry.key}" />

        <ul>
            <li th:text="${entry.value[0]}" />
            <li th:text="${entry.value[1]}" />
            <li th:text="${entry.value[2]}" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```